# Is there a name for an orange, gray and white -style pattern?

Tags: terminology

I've heard somewhere that an orange, gray and white "style" has a specific name. I believe that it has "minimalism" in it, but I cannot recall.

[**Here is an example of the color scheme**](https://www.google.lv/search?q=gray%20orange%20white%20design&biw=1536&bih=764&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiprrSOhrvNAhXFVSwKHUY2CJYQ_AUICCgB), but in my case it's more about user interfaces design in software, corporate logo style, corporate branding and so on.

Is there an actual name for this style?

Comment: If I had to describe it, I'd say 'Achromatic colours with a contrast colour'. Probably not what you're looking for, but maybe it helps to find what you're looking for.

Comment: Your question, seeing as it relates specifically to digital art, may be better asked on [Graphicdesign.se]. I have posted a general answer as it relates to color theory and I focus on items that could be handmade like pottery and paintings... but there may be an industry term that we are unfamiliar with.

Comment: In interior design, the orange would be called the "accent color"

Answer (score 5):

Based on the images you've shown, where the main colors are the shades of grey, I'd call it grayscale with a single accent color, in this specific case, the accent color is orange.

You could also call it black and white with a single accent color but that might lead people to believe that *only* black and white were used rather than shades of gray.

Something similar can be seen in these ceramic items:

[image: White and grey teapot with orange accents][image: Black and white pot with orange]

If you were talking more about something like this tea kettle:

[image: Orange kettle with grey accents]

It would be the opposite - orange with grayscale accents.

If you're using multiple shades of the same orange (same color, different amounts of white/black), it would be "[monochromatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochromatic_color)", like the image below, which is an underpainting of a [finished painting](http://www.artistsnetwork.com/articles/art-demos-techniques/indirect-painting-route-by-michael-chesley-johnson):

[image: Monochromatic image]